# Angular - set overlay margin depending on its position strategy

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay, angular-cdk-overlay

I'm working on a custom overlay component and I need to set a margin on it. It should be `0.5rem` depending on the position of the overlay (e.g. `originY === 'bottom' => margin-top: 0.5rem`, and so on). I was hoping to use `PositionStrategy` object for this but it looks like there's no such info available on it.

```typescript
private getOverlayConfig(origin: HTMLElement): OverlayConfig {
  const positionStrategy = this.calculatePosition(origin);
  // was hoping for something like this
  // const panelClass = positionStrategy.originY === 'bottom' ? 'panel-margin-top' : 'panel-margin-bottom'
  return new OverlayConfig({
    positionStrategy,
    panelClass,
    //...
  })
}
```

`PositionStrategy` object exposes only four methods (`apply`, `attach`, `detach`, `dispose`) which are of no use to me and I can't access anything else.

As for a CSS solution I can't imagine it. The overlay can open either a template or a component and since they are placed in an overlay, I have no idea how to compare the position of the overlay with the origin position (button which opened the overlay).

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can set the `panelClass` when providing a position strategy. And it works great.

```typescript
private getPositions(): ConnectionPositionPair[] {
  return [
    // This strategy opens the panel below the origin => add margin on top
    {
      panelClass: 'panel-margin-top',
      originX: 'start',
      originY: 'bottom',
      overlayX: 'start',
      overlayY: 'top'
    },
    //...
  ]
}
```

Honestly I didn't expect the panelClass to be part of a position object but in a hindsight it make sense.