# Change Angular CDK Overlay positioning

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to change default Overlay positioning. My code looks like this:

```
config.positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
          .global()
          .left(origin.left+'px')
          .top(origin.top+'px');
```

and by default `.cdk-overlay-pane` element has this configuration:

```
element.style {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    position: static;
    margin-left: 412px;
    margin-top: 803px;
}
```

Is there's a possibility to change `position` and `margins` for `top/left` and looking like this?

```
element.style {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    **position: absolute;
    left: 412px;
    top: 803px;**
}
```

I was looking for it in Overlay and PositionStrategy, but still I don't know where to find files responsible for creating `.cdk-overlay-pane` element.

Comment: I once had a similar issue, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181051/3359635. There is a `panelClass` for overlay, which you might be able to use.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using this to add custom class to this overlay, but in this cas it won't work. Position is dynamic and I cannot predefine it in css file.